# Visual studio does not create the content folder in an asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When running my project, the browser can't find the content folder - as in pictures below [image from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO6qY.png) and [image from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK0nu.png).

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you were expecting. Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: You probably have a routing issue.  Can you post some code from your controller?

Comment: <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

Comment: the above files doesnot exist

Comment: so the output page not styled

Comment: iam a beginner in asp.net this is the first code

Comment: visual studio show this errors  
07:54:44.7135: Referenced file '~/Scripts/_references.js' not found.
07:54:45.2689: Referenced file '~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js' not found.
07:54:45.2769: Referenced file '~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js' not found.

Comment: this error shown in the browser Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: May be the Content folder not included in the project?